# Vue Router External Auth - Redirect to Login Page and Bounce Back to Home Page

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router, cas

I'm trying to add [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas) auth to my site (an admin dashboard) but I'm having trouble with handling the routing to/from the external login website. I'm not sure how to setup the VueRouter to use `beforeEnter` to determine if the user has already been authenticated. In many of the examples I see online the authentication is all done locally, but in the case of using CAS all of the authentication is done externally. I was doing a lot of playing around and I was able to successfully implement the functionality I'm looking for (unauthorized users redirect to CAS login, bounce back on successful login) in a separate `auth.js` file using Express, but I'm not sure how/if it's even possible to integrate that code into my project. As far as I'm aware the route handling in my `auth.js` file is done using Express but I'd like to use VueRouter to handle all the routing on my actual site. I have virtually no experience with JS routing (I've only used Flask prior) so if anything I've said sounds very dumb that's probably because it is and if anything is confusing I will definitely try to clear things up.

Here is my current `routes.js`:

```js
const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    component: DashboardLayout,
    redirect: "/dashboard",
    children: [{
        path: "dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        // beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        //   check if user is logged in
        //       if not redirect to CAS login
        //       else next()
        // },
        component: Dashboard
      },
      {
        path: "scene-builder",
        name: "scene-builder",
        component: SceneBuilder
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        name: "profile",
        component: Profile
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        name: "login",
        component: Login
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    component: NotFound
  },
];

export default routes;
```

`index.js`:

```js
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import routes from "./routes";

// configure router
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes, 
  linkExactActiveClass: "active",
  scrollBehavior: (to) => {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash
      }
    } else {
      return {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    }
  }
});

export default router;
```

Here is my `auth.js` that redirects a user to the CAS login site and works, but I'm not sure if I can use the code when integrating CAS into my project.

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const CASAuthentication = require("express-cas-authentication");
const BindLdap = require('./bind_ldap.js');
const ldap = require('ldapjs');
const app = express();

const serviceURL = "http://localhost:3000"
const casURL = "https://cas-auth.{college_name}.edu/cas";

var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: ['ldaps://ldap.{college_name}.edu:636']
});

// configure the session, storing the token
// we receive from the SSO service as a cookie
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

const cas = new CASAuthentication({
  cas_url: casURL,
  service_url: serviceURL,
  cas_version: "3.0",
  session_info: "cas_userinfo"
});

app.get("/", cas.bounce, function(req, res) {
  var uuid = req.session[cas.session_name];
  BindLdap.search_ldap(uuid, client).then(function(user_data) {
    res.json(user_data);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

app.get("/app", cas.block, function (req, res) {
  res.json({cas_user: req.session[cas.session_name]});
});

app.get("/logout", cas.logout);

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: In general, if you can CAS login via a REST endpoint, then you can Vue route to a component that processes the login endpoint, and possibly store some login response info in the Vue client, possibly Vuex.